# Bitmap size exceed VM budget while using gallery and imageviews

Tags: android

I am trying to implement the code written under "Imageswitcher View" on this link

http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-3-more-views

When I click first Image it enlarges but on clicking the second image the code crashes but if I start from the second image it does not crash .

Logcat says

```
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:349)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:498)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:473)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:501)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:280)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at com.k.TestingActivity$1.onItemClick(TestingActivity.java:47)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.widget.Gallery.onSingleTapUp(Gallery.java:867)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:557)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.widget.Gallery.onTouchEvent(Gallery.java:842)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1125)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1675)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2194)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1878)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-08 22:15:08.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1349):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post YOUR code so we can see what your doing, but only the relevant parts of it.

Comment: There are many different solutions to this.  See the list of similar questions on the right.

Comment: The simplest Reason of the crash is HEAP is overflow, so that you should use reduced size images, or optimize your code that unused objects should be free, so that you can utilize memory more gracefully.